# all finite start sequences of decimal representation of $\pi$ decidable?

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines

$L^1 \subset \{0,\dots 9\}^*$ consits of all finite start sequences of the decimal representation of $\pi$ (without comma). Is L decidable?

I guess it is not, but I do not know how to prove it. Help is much appreciated

Comment: Are you saying that $L$ contains `3`, `31`, `314`, `3141`, `31415`, and so on, but not `415926`? That would be clearly decidable.

Comment: @HenningMakholm yes. But how does one prove it? I am totally new to this topic

Comment: @JohnDoe: By specifying an algorithm to do the decision; e.g. compute the leading digits of $\pi$ and check if they match the digits you were given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily decidable by the following procedure:

1. Count the length of the input string.
2. Compute that many digits of $\pi$.
3. Accept if the digits you computed are identical to the input string; otherwise reject.

---

If you can't assume as a known fact that it's possible to compute digits of $\pi$, then the question becomes one about real analysis more than one about computability. There are then various possible approaches; a relatively simple one would be:

To ask whether, say, `3141592653521` is in your $L$ is to ask whether $\pi$ is between $\frac{3141592653521}{1000000000000}$ and $\frac{3141592653522}{1000000000000}$. (It can't be equal to either of these endpoints because we know $\pi$ is irrational). So what we need is to be able to *compare* $\pi$ to arbitrary rational numbers. We can do that by this procedure

1. If $x<3$ then $x<\pi$.
2. If $x>4$ then $x>\pi$.
3. Otherwise, if $\cos \frac x2 > 0$ then $x<\pi$, and if $\cos \frac x2<0$ then $x>\pi$.

For the last step we can compute the cosine from the power series:
$$ \cos x = 1 - \frac12 x^2 + \frac1{24}x^4 - \frac1{720}x^6 + \cdots + (-1)^n \frac{1}{(2n)!}x^{2n} + \cdots $$
After the first two terms (when $x<2$), this is an *absolutely decreasing alternating series*, which means that we can know the sign of the limit in finite time by finding the first time where we have just *added* something and yet the sum so far is *negative*, **or** we have just *subtracted* something and yet the sum so far is *positive*. Since we know the limit is not $0$ (the cosine of a rational number never is), this will happen sooner or later, and therefore our decision procedure terminates.

Note that all numbers encountered during this computation are *rational*, so we can keep everything as exact fractions throughout -- there's no floating-point arithmetic involved.